Проблема с установкой PyTorch 1.9.0 на Windows 10 x64 с Python 3.8 с использованием pip
Я пытаюсь установить PyTorch 1.9.0 на мою систему Windows 10 с 64-битной архитектурой и Python 3.8, но pip не может найти соответствующую версию. Когда я пытаюсь установить его с помощью команды:
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio

я получаю следующую ошибку:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Чтобы решить проблему, я попробовал скачать соответствующий .whl файл с сайта https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/ и выбрал torch-1.9.0+cpu-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl.
Однако при попытке установить его с помощью команды:
pip install torch-1.9.0+cpu-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

я получаю следующую ошибку:
ERROR: torch-1.9.0+cpu-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Дополнительные детали:

Операционная система: Windows 10 x64
Версия Python: 3.8


У вас точно-точно винда x64? Как-то странно.

Хорошо видно @CrazyElf , в этом и была проблема, 32-битная версия Python

Блин, я и забыл, что сам Питон тоже может быть 32-битный. Я думал его давно уже никто и не ставит ))  Конечно, для питорча просто даже памяти было бы мало на 32-битном питоне, естественно, он его не поддерживает.

Это старый компьютер, на котором я, поскольку наступил отпуск, разрабатываю новые программы. Я обновлю это @CrazyElf

Проблема в том, что я использую 32-битную версию Python, что явно видно в нескольких местах в выводе команды pip debug, например:

sys.version: [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] (компилятор C, использованный для компиляции Python).
sys.platform: win32.
Теги совместимости: нигде не указано win64, вместо этого указано: cp38-cp38-win32.

Моя операционная система 64-битная, загруженный пакет предназначен для CPython 3.8 64-бит (версия для процессора, не CUDA), но интерпретатор Python 32-битный, и, насколько я помню, PyTorch никогда не поддерживал 32-битные системы.

мне нужно использовать именно Python 3.8 для моего проекта, проблем быть не должно, так как это минимальная версия, поддерживаемая PyTorch, но мне нужно будет установить 64-битную версию интерпретатора.

Последняя версия ветки 3.8, для которой предоставляется официальный установщик, — Python 3.8.10:
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.10/python-3.8.10-amd64.exe.
Последняя версия — 3.8.18, но начиная с 3.8.10 это только обновления безопасности, и бинарные файлы не предоставляются, их придется компилировать самостоятельно.

я бы обновить как Python, так и PyTorch, тем более что поддержка Python 3.8 завершится через пару месяцев (в конце октября 2024 года).



Я не буду пытаться рассказывать, что время не стоит на месте, что программное обеспечение развивалось и будет развиваться, что современная версия 3.12.5, что 32-разрядные системы СДОХЛИ, что всё надо делать вовремя, что потом кто-то будет после Вас всё переписывать... Вы сами породили эти проблемы и даже не понимаете, что решать их надо было уже ВЧЕРА. На самом деле, на их решение не уйдёт даже пары часов. Но... пишем комменты...

К сожалению, я не могу выбрать версию Python, на которой хочу работать @FoxFox

И почему же? Вы хоть пробовали? А вот это: "...я бы обновить как Python, так и PyTorch, тем более что поддержка Python 3.8 завершится через пару месяцев (в конце октября 2024 года)...". Это в следующем тысячелетии? Что дальше?
"...Последняя версия ветки 3.8, для которой предоставляется официальный установщик, — Python 3.8.10..."  - серьёзно? И где ж это все остальные нашли 3.12.5?1 Наверное, рептилоиды подсуетили... :-)))
"...бинарные файлы не предоставляются..." - тоже серьёзно? А опции установки пытались когда-нибудь разглядывать? Ах, да, 3.8 было последний раз, несколько лет назад...

Запросы/заказы клиентов @FoxFox

У меня всё работает, вот в чём сухой остаток. В том числе и этот торч. Остальное всё - разговоры, для развлечения. Проблема не у меня.

Если мне не изменяет память, я начал переезжать на Питон, переписывая свои проги с одного языка на другой, тогда, когда версия Питона была 3.8.2. Сегодня 3.12.5. Версия вышла несколько дней назад. Мои скрипты как работали, так и работают. Все, без исключения. В том числе и в автономном варианте. А разве должно было быть иначе?! Я кодирую базы данных и системные утилиты 30 лет. Мне почти 60. Все версии Windows я лично инсталлировал, начал программировать ещё на калькуляторе когда-то, в 1992. Весь софт у меня суперсовременный. ВЕСЬ.

＿|￣|○ Ту - великий Герой Stackoverfиалистического Труда @FoxFox ‍♀️‍♂️

Пишем комменты... Ну, пишем. А как насчёт воза? И ныне там? Ржунимагу.

Windows 11 (24H2), Python 3.12.5:
pip install -U --compile torch
pip install -U --compile torchvision
pip install -U --compile torchaudio

Всё установилось без малейших проблем. Однако, обращаю внимание, что сие великозаумное творение сносит более новые библиотеки и устанавливает более старые (например, numpy).
Я не знаю, где берут пользователи вот такой синтаксис, если даже на сайте этого торча об установке написано ИНАЧЕ?

Большое спасибо за ваш ответ Fox Fox. К сожалению, это дает ту же ошибку:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfying the requirement torch==1.9.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.9.0

Именно мои команды использовали? Если да, Вам пора переустанавливать, быть может только Питон и все модули, а скорее всего Windows. Как видите, даже если Вы достучитесь до самых крутых гуру в сообществе, Вам скажут: проблемы нет у нас, она у Вас.

Дезинсталлируется это всё, на всякий случай, тоже нормально, что я и сделал.
